# pdf external streams in Max OS X Preview

Tags: macos, pdf

According to the specification, a part of a PDF document can reside in an external file. An example for an image:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 117
/Height 117
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Length 0
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/FFilter /DCTDecode
/F (pinguine.jpg)
>>
stream
endstream
endobj
```

I found that this functionality does work in Adobe Acrobat 5.0 for Windows ([sample PDF](http://bitplant.de/downloads/2011/01/dirimg/directimg.pdf) with the [image](http://bitplant.de/downloads/2011/01/dirimg/pinguine.jpg)), also I managed to view this file in Adobe Acrobat Reader 8.1.3 for Mac OS X after I found the setting "Allow external content". Unfortunately, it seems that non-Adobe tools ignore the external stream feature. I hope I'm wrong, therefore ask the question:

How to enable external streams in Mac OS X? (I think that all the system Mac OS X tools use the same library, therefore say "Mac OS X" instead of "Preview".)

Or maybe there could be a programming hook to emulate external streams? My task is: store a big set of images (total ˜300Mb) outside of a small PDF (˜1Mb). At some moment, I want to filter PDF through a quartz filter and get a PDF with the images embedded. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is the PDF that only "links" to the images now **more** portable, because it is more "light-weight", or **less** portable because the documents data resides in separate files, being prone not to "ported" along with the pdf file? The feature should be available since version `%PDF-1.2`, but it can only be hoped for nobody else then Adobe implements it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X/Quartz does not support external streams and there is no way to "hook" into it.